# Sandcastle Help File Builder Plug-In "XPath Reflection File Filter": How to?

Tags: xpath, plugins, sandcastle

I would like to use Eric Woodruff's Sandcastle Help File Builder to produce localized help files. My idea is to add a 'lang' attribute to the documentation tags like:

```
  ''' <summary lang="en">
  ''' Initializes a new instance ...
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <summary lang="de">
  ''' Initialisiert eine neue Instanz ...
  ''' </summary>
  Sub New()
  ...
```

Then adding the Plug-In "XPath Reflection File Filter" to remove unwanted items with XPpath filter

```
//*[@lang != "en"]
```

[image: see picture]

But this does not delete the items tagged with lang="de". They are still present.

What is my fault?

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath filter for attributes would use an `@`:

```
//*[@lang != "en"]
```

alternatively, to also match elements *without* a `lang` attribute:

```
//*[not(@lang = "en")]
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Look at the picture, I just did it in this way. I'll correct my post.

Comment: @Ulrich Ah, I see. Then I have no other suggestion than than to try to find the error inductively, i.e. start with `//*`, then `//summary`, then some expressions to test that predicates work at all, like `//summary[true()]`, or `//summary[text() > '']`, then a different attribute than `@lang`, etc, you get the idea: Expand from the least specific expression possible until it starts to break.

Answer (score 0):

None of the hints had success. I developed a solution with a XPath app. You can find it at [Ullis Roboter Seite](http://bienonline.magix.net/public/dotnet-localize-doc-en.html).